# Android ActionBarSherlock - Add home button and Tabs

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need to add 4 buttons (1 imageview and 3 textview tabs) to my actionbar. I am using actionbar sherlock and I added these 4 tabs, but the problem is the actionbar tabs are not proportionally aligned.

[image]

This is how I should implement the actionbar. The actionbar should have a fix with disabling the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This document may be helpful for you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding